# How do I show a list of recently published documents

Tags: document-library, page-layout, document, team-sites

What I want is to display a list of recently added/released documents to my document library on my team site (ootb). I don't want to create a view in the document library, I just want people who visit a page of the subsite to be able to get a sense of what new documents have been uploaded without having to visit the document library.

I've seen similar questions asked before, but the answer always seems to be "create a view," which I have already done.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Document Library as a webpart on the homepage of subsite?

Comment: How do I do that? I am very new to SharePoint, so I have a basic understanding of how things work but my knowledge is limited

Comment: Your suggestion worked and is exactly what I was looking for. The site admin. had added a completely new Document Library list as a web part, which threw me off because I was trying to figure out why the two weren't linked. Once I deleted that and added a new one, it was clear that it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Heads up for other newbies by the way, you may run into disappearing web parts like I did. Reference this website if you do: http://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2013/04/23/sharepoint-and-the-disappearing-webparts/

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be a content query web part. You can configure the web part to get documents from your library and apply condition to show recently modified documents. You can point web part to a document library in parent site or even in sub site. This web part is also OOTB web part.

Comment: could a content query web part be configured with a condition to only show recently published document? I modify drafts often, so I only want to show major revisions